# Showing TextArea in one Line

Tags: java, user-interface

```
    JPanel leftPanel     = new JPanel();
    JPanel leftTopPanel  = new JPanel();
    JPanel leftDownPanel = new JPanel();
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();

    textArea.setBackground(Color.red);
    textArea.setText("DESCRIPTION");
    textArea.setEnabled(false);

    leftPanel.setLayout( new GridLayout(2,1));

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(10,10));

    leftPanel.add(leftTopPanel);
    leftPanel.add(scrollPane);
    return leftPanel;
```

Hi everyone. I am trying to make a textArea which basially will get description from database.

Here is the problem. When I write the real description in to TextArea, It always shows me the Description in one line. How can I fix it ?

THANKS :)

Comment: I think these are the two methods you're looking for: `textArea.setLineWrap(true);` and `textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);`

Comment: This is crazy chit: `scrollPane.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(10,10));`. Instead set the rows and line properties of your JTextArea.